# R read tab separated text file

Tags: r, read.table

I have a rather messy tab separated text file that looks something like this (here are 2 first rows):

```
1.5 dp  lax4    {107:107,111:111,508:508,509:509,654:654,662:662,685:685}   [107,662,685,508,111,654,509]   drudgereport.com    appnexus    http://drudgereport.com/    c       1454822402  2016    2   7   5
1.5 dp  lax4    {10175:10175,10325:10325,310:310,313:313,316:316,365:365,380:380,509:509}   [310,365,509,316,313,380,10175,10325]   www.worldlifestyle.com  appnexus    http://www.worldlifestyle.com/beauty-style/most-iconic-wedding-dresses-in-history-14d/16    c       1454824483  2016    2   7   5
```

when trying to load it to R with read table:

```
data <- read.table("nir_test.csv",header = FALSE, sep = "\t")
```

I get an error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 2478 did not have 15 elements
```

Any help with the correct way to read these kind of files appreciated
thanks

UPDATE:
Here is the proplematic line:

```
1.5 dp  lax4    {307:307,564:564}   [307,564]   riskofrain.wikia.com    appnexus    http://riskofrain.wikia.com/wiki/Character_Unlocks  c       1454824416  2016    2   75
```

the problem is that the last 2 columns are not separated by tab (7 and 5), actually are not separated at all

Comment: give this a try: [klick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296799/how-can-i-read-a-matrix-with-missing-end-elements-in-r)

Comment: thanks to Abaddon666 goto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296799/how-can-i-read-a-matrix-with-missing-end-elements-in-r

Comment: Using `fill=TRUE` works - I tested it.